# Pthread strange behavior and Segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, pthread-barriers

I am trying to write a parallel simulator, that uses threads. But I cannot find what causes segmentation fault and why threads seem to get stuck on a barrier sometimes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int num_threads = 5;

//Thread arguemnt struct
struct ThreadArguments {
        unsigned int id;
        pthread_barrier_t* barrier;
        char* array;  
        char* copy_array; 
};

void simulate(struct ThreadArguments* args);

void initializeThreads( struct ThreadArguments* data,  char* letters);


// Main method
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int i;
        char* letters = malloc((num_threads + 1) *sizeof(char)); //plus 1 for /0
        struct ThreadArguments *data = malloc(num_threads * sizeof(struct ThreadArguments));
        initializeThreads(data, letters);

        pthread_t *thread = malloc(num_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));

        // Launching Threads
        for (i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
                printf("Create threads %d \n", i);
                fflush(stdout);
                pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,(void *) &simulate,(void *) &data[i]);
        }

        // Waiting for Threads to Finish
        for (i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
                pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
        }
        return 0;
}

void initializeThreads( struct ThreadArguments* data,  char* letters)
{
        int i;
        pthread_barrier_t barrier;  //create a barrier
        pthread_barrier_init (&barrier, NULL, num_threads);

        char *copy_letters = malloc((num_threads + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if(copy_letters == NULL)      //Checking malloc
        {
                perror("Error mallocing");
                free(copy_letters);
                return;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        {
                data[i].barrier = &barrier;
                data[i].array = letters;
                data[i].copy_array = copy_letters;
                data[i].id = i;
        }

}

void simulate(struct ThreadArguments* args)
{

        struct ThreadArguments* my_args= (struct ThreadArguments*)args;
        printf("thread %d started", my_args->id);
        fflush(stdout);

        if(my_args->id == 0)  //print the initial state of the board
        {
                printf("0th thread prints out results");
        }

        ///Main loop. Each iteration is one round of simulation

        my_args->copy_array[my_args->id] = my_args->array[my_args->id];
        //DO SOME WORK HERE

        //barrier
        pthread_barrier_wait (my_args->barrier);
}
```

I tried commenting out parts and tracing it with valgrind ( and helgrind tool)but still was not able understand what causes error. 
The code could be tested with ./simulator test.txt 0  0 1
where test.txt is the following

What is wrong with the way I implement barriers? and what causes SEGFAULT?
EDIT:
Updated with a shorter version of the code. This code just wants to create num_thread number of threads and each of them would copy one elements from array to another.

Comment: There is way too much code here.

Comment: I tried posting less and people said its hard to see if the code could not be compiled

Comment: But you could try a *little* harder to make a compact working example.Your `evolve` function contains about 70 lines of commented out code for example. You say you are getting a segfault. Where in the code is the segfault occurring?

Comment: Why are you passing the `filename` as `char**`..simply pass the `filename` and catch it with `char*`

Comment: Please provide a shorter version of code or mention where are you getting the segmentation fault

Comment: @Mayukh Sarka I have shortened the code to only show most important parts. It still produces segmentation fault in pthread_join or gets stuck waiting at a barrier.

Comment: Change `pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,(void *) &simulate,(void *) &data[i]);` to `pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, simulate, &data[i]);`. But you may have other problems.

Comment: @AlexSmirnov Your `data` is already a pointer and in `pthread_create` you are passing address of the pointer and hence I think you need to catch it with `struct ThreadArguments** args` in `simulate` function...or else just simply pass `data[i]` instead of `&data[i]`

Comment: I though about it, but it gives an error `simulation.c:43:25: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
                         pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,(void *) &simulate,(void *) data[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
void initializeThreads( struct ThreadArguments* data,  char* letters)
{
    int i;
    pthread_barrier_t barrier;  //create a barrier
```

You created `barrier` on the stack in `initializeThreads`, so when this function returns, it ceases to exist. So all the threads you create are accessing an object that no longer exists through a stale pointer.

Comment: should I malloc() it or what is the best approach?

Comment: That would be a reasonable solution.